# Show and Hide DIV Class from different page file

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css, ajax

**I have two different PHP files:**

> 1. index.php
> 2. show.php

-

```
index.php

<ul>
<li><a href="show.php?id=1">Show Div 1</a></li>
<li><a href="show.php?id=2">Show Div 2</a></li>
<li><a href="show.php?id=3">Show Div 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

-

```
show.php

<style type="text/css">
.div1 {display:none;}
.div2 {display:none;}
.div3 {display:none;}
</style>

<div class="div1">Div 1 Content</div>
<div class="div2">Div 2 Content</div>
<div class="div3">Div 3 Content</div>
```

-

When you read the css style in the `show.php`, there are no content will be displayed.

If user click which one of `<li>` from `index.php`, user can only see the `.div` on `show.php` which that `<li>` clicked from the `index.php`.

I assuming this method will make less files. (exactly like what I'm wondering)

Because all contents in which to be shown, are in one file (`show.php`).

Well, how to make each `<li>` from `index.php` will only show the content from each div in `show.php`.

Comment: Definitely an XY problem - see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Thanks for the link, useful article :)

Answer (score 1):

You want this in show.php

```
<?php $id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : 0; ?>
<style type="text/css">
.div1, .div2, .div3 {display: none}
<?php if($id == 1) {
    echo '.div1 {display: block; }';
} elseif($id == 2) {
    echo '.div2 {display: block; }';
} elseif($id == 3) {
    echo '.div3 {display: block; }';
}
</style>

<div class="div1">Div 1 Content</div>
<div class="div2">Div 2 Content</div>
<div class="div3">Div 3 Content</div>
```

Comment: Why do you copy a bad pattern from the question. What is the purpose of sending content where 2/3 is hidden?

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo Because it answered his question directly, and probably in a way he could understand better. I commented above that your method is better.

Comment: Have you heard about XY problem?

Comment: see my edited answer or my comment to the question. 2 links for the meta is enough - I'm not a spammer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work, but keep in mind this is sort of a "hack". There's better ways to accomplish this, but they'd fall outside of the scope of your question.

index.php:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="show.php?id=1">Show Div 1</a></li>
<li><a href="show.php?id=2">Show Div 2</a></li>
<li><a href="show.php?id=3">Show Div 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

show.php:

```
<style type="text/css">
.div1 {display:none;}
.div2 {display:none;}
.div3 {display:none;}

<? if($_GET['id']==1) { echo ".div1 {display:block;" } ?>
<? if($_GET['id']==2) { echo ".div2 {display:block;" } ?>
<? if($_GET['id']==3) { echo ".div3 {display:block;" } ?>
</style>
<div class="div1">Div 1 Content</div>
<div class="div2">Div 2 Content</div>
<div class="div3">Div 3 Content</div>
```

Comment: That will throw up errors if there is no ID set. See my answer below.

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo But if someone goes to show.php from an external link, Google for instance, there is no guarantee that your Get variable will be there. Google will index that page separately and without any Get variable.

Comment: It won't throw up errors if no ID is set, it'll just display a page with no content shown.

Comment: @TimWasson, it depends on the error level settings. The ideal solution is to send HTTP response 404 in this case, but in the current form of code in this answer it's impossible, because headers have already been send.

Comment: @TimWasson if no ID is set and you try to access that variable it will throw up a `Notice: Undefined variable`. Just as if you try to access any variable that doesn't exist. If you can't see it then you have them suppressed.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bad approach - you should send only relevant content in response - not a bunch of hidden divs.

Edited after comment from @Styphon.

*show.php*

```
<div>
<?php
    $id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : 0;
    if($id == "1"){
        echo "Div 1 Content";
    }
    else if ($id == "2"){
        echo "Div 2 Content";
    }
    else if ($id == "3"){
        echo "Div 3 Content";
    }
    else{
        echo "Default content";
    }
?>
</div>
```

After comments arguing that, this is a better approach but doesn't answer the original question. Please read https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem
This question is an example of XY problem.

Comment: This is definitely the better approach, but you need to account for there being no GET variable of ID, by checking for it with isset first, otherwise that will throw up errors.

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, either way you go about this is a hack. Your answer is definitely a better approach but didn't really answer the original question.

Comment: +1 for @Styphon note about checking for $_GET['id'] presence.

Comment: Got two downvotes, one from @TimWasson I assume - maybe you will reconsider it - read the end of my answer after last edit. The other peer that has downvoted, I kindly ask you to comment - I'm open to constructive criticism. What is wrong in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

index.php:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="show.php?id=1">Show Div 1</a></li>
<li><a href="show.php?id=2">Show Div 2</a></li>
<li><a href="show.php?id=3">Show Div 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

show.php:

```
<style type="text/css">
.hidden {display:none;}
.display {display: block;}
</style>
<div class="<?php if(!isset($_GET['id'])||$_GET['id']==1) echo 'display'; else echo 'hidden'; ?>">Div 1 Content (default)</div>
<div class="<?php if(isset($_GET['id'])&&$_GET['id']==2) echo 'display'; else echo 'hidden'; ?>">Div 2 Content</div>
<div class="<?php if(isset($_GET['id'])&&$_GET['id']==3) echo 'display'; else echo 'hidden'; ?>">Div 3 Content</div>
```